# Smoothen the animation of Casino wheel

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am developing a casino based game using html5. The animation is working properly but this is not quite smooth i.e. once the wheel stops rotation I move ball as a final repositioning to smoothen the transition but it is not upto the expectation. Complete [Code here](http://jsfiddle.net/codeomnitrix/vv42n/)

BallReposition Function - runs after I wheel stops movement for the final repositioning of the ball to give some reality to the animation.

```
function ballReposition(){
curX = findNearestOnCircle(curX);
 if(curX > deadXRight){
        sign = "-";
    }else if(curX < deadXLeft){
        sign = "+";
    }       
    if(sign == "+"){
        curX = parseInt(curX) + ballRepositionIncVal;
        curY = Math.floor(Math.abs(getYOnCircle(curX, 130, 1)) + 0.5);      
    }else{
        curX = parseInt(curX) - ballRepositionIncVal;           
        curY = Math.floor(Math.abs(getYOnCircle(curX, 130, 0)) + 0.5);
    }
    var xy = normalizeXY(curX, curY);

    curX = parseInt(xy.split("-")[0]);
    curY = parseInt(xy.split("-")[1]);
    surface = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var surfaceContext = surface.getContext("2d");
    //removing older ball image.
    surfaceContext.save();
    // Translate to the center point of our image
    surfaceContext.translate(happy.width * 0.5, happy.height * 0.5);
    // Perform the rotation
    surfaceContext.rotate(DegToRad(angle));
    // Translate back to the top left of our image

    surfaceContext.translate(-happy.width * 0.5, -happy.height * 0.5);             
    surface.getContext("2d").drawImage(happy, 0, 0);
    surface.getContext("2d").drawImage(ball, curX, curY);
    console.log(curX + curY);
    surfaceContext.restore();

    ballRepositionIncVal-=5;
    if(ballRepositionIncVal <= 0){
        clearInterval(myIntervalVar);
    }
```

}

Other function details -

1. drawCanvas - loads the images and once the images are loaded it will start calling loop function which will rotate the wheel and move the ball in anticlockwise direction.
2. normalizeXY - used to put the ball at some discrete positions i.e. proper positions below numbers of wheel.

EDIT - Fiddle Configuration updated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vv42n/1/)

Comment: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vv42n/1/) - you had wrong config.

Comment: Thanks Shadow, for updating the fiddle configuration. Can you please help me to smoothen the animation

Comment: Just upvoted for the animation

Comment: If you want a more realistic behaviour, you have to simulate it : have the ball roll and bounce just like a real one. But your code need some redesign before you go further.

Comment: Vincent can you please explain it a bit more.

Answer (score 4):

To create a realistic spinning wheel you can use a logarithmic-ish approach to reduce the speed of the wheel.

This means the angle is decremented by small per-centage for each frame. As it is per-centage you will get a smooth ending spin (you will also notice you get the infamous [wagon wheel aliasing effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect)).

**[This online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/EGmD4/)** shows the loop isolated (implement as you please):

```
var angle = 2;          /// start angle in radians
ctx.translate(w, h);    /// prepare canvas for rotation (w and h = 50%)

ctx.globalAlpha = 0.67; /// optional bonus: motion blur(-ish)
loop();                 /// start loop

function loop() {

    ctx.rotate(a);      /// use incremental rotation
    ctx.drawImage(img, -w , -h);

    /// spin down and only loop if angle > certain value
    a *= 0.995;

    /// continue if there is enough "inertia"
    if (a > 0.001) requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

The threshold value for continue the loop determines how "brutal" you want the stop to be. If you want the wheel to appear heavier (more mass) you can decrement the angle with an even tinier increment (eg. try `0.998`).

For the ball to bounce around you need to resort to physics modelling, or at least pseudo-physics-modelling. This includes collision detections for all the small details on the wheel as well as sub-time-steps (ray casting) checking and positioning in z-axis.

I feel this is a bit broad to describe here on SO but find a good article on collision detection and physics simulation. [Here is a good start with the basics](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Collision_Detection_and_Physics_FAQ).